# Modify dataframe based on grouping of rows and update columns based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe on which I need to apply condition based on same values of rows in few columns and update other columns.

Input DataFrame Code:

```
df = DataFrame({
    'exp':['1y','1y','1y','1y','1y','1y'],
    'mat':['1y','1y','1y','2y','2y','2y'],
    'reg':['in', 'in', 'in', 'in', 'in', 'in'],
    'con':['w','s','c','w','s','c'],
    'val':[2.5,0,-2.5,2.5,0,-2.5],
    'rs':[6, 10, 4, 12, 30, 6 ]
})
df
```

Input dataframe:

```
    exp mat reg con val  rs
0   1y  1y  in  w   2.5   6
1   1y  1y  in  s   0.0  10
2   1y  1y  in  c   -2.5  4
3   1y  2y  in  w   2.5  12
4   1y  2y  in  s   0.0  30
5   1y  2y  in  c   -2.5. 6
```

Expected Output dataframe:

```
    exp mat reg con val  rs
0   1y  1y  in  w   2.5  5
1   1y  1y  in  s   0.0  10
2   1y  1y  in  c   -2.5 1
3   1y  2y  in  w   2.5  9
4   1y  2y  in  s   0.0  30
5   1y  2y  in  c   -2.5 3
```

Multiple conditions are based on rows and columns:

1. For same values in rows of columns
   like for all 3 rows having exp=1y, mat=1y, reg=in.

   a. Update column 'rs' based on col 'con'.

   ```
     if 'con' == w, then rs = (current_rs + rs(con == c)) / 2  i.e (6+4)/2 
     if 'con' == s, then no changes
     if 'con' == c, then rs = (rs(con == w) - current_rs)) / 2 i.e (6-4)/2
   ```
2. Apply same conditions from group of 3 rows, where exp=1y, mat=2y, reg=in

My dataset is quite large and there any many other regions and many more combinations of 'exp', 'mat' and 'reg' columns.
I have tried many things like groupby, iloc, np.where, filter but could not succeed.

Unsuccessful Attempt:

```
df.groupby(['exp','mat','reg']) # not sure what can be the next condition
```

Comment: You should not remove your attempt from the post...

Comment: I just removed my attempts to make the question shorter,  modified the question also to make it clearer.

Comment: Hey, I was about to copy your dataframe intialization. :-(

Comment: Many people would want to see real attempt and in some case, it might be some simple things that you overlooked. Plus, what you posted there wasn't that long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unstack your data so that `con` becomes the columns, then you can work on modifying the data easily:

```
tmp = df.set_index(['exp','mat','reg','con']).unstack()
tmp[('rs','w')],tmp[('rs','c')] = ((tmp[('rs','w')] + tmp[('rs','c')])/2,
                                   (tmp[('rs','w')] - tmp[('rs','c')])/2)
tmp.stack().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  exp mat reg con    val    rs
0  1y  1y  in   c   -2.5   1.0
1  1y  1y  in   s    0.0  10.0
2  1y  1y  in   w    2.5   5.0
3  1y  2y  in   c   -2.5   3.0
4  1y  2y  in   s    0.0  30.0
5  1y  2y  in   w    2.5   9.0
```

Comment: Quang Hoang - I'm solving a similar problem with almost similar df but with many more columns where also I have to do addition and subtraction on rs column but I'm getting 'Value Error: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape'. Just wanted a suggestion if I can unstack it with some workaround or will I have to go for some other option like pivot, pivot_table etc.

Comment: When you have `duplicate entries` error, it's mean somewhere you have several rows with the same combination `(exp, mat, reg, con)`. `pivot` will fail as it is equivalent to `unstack()`, `pivot_table` will average them. What do you want to do in this case?

Comment: I need to apply the same logic in 'rs' column:
tmp[('rs','w')],tmp[('rs','c')] = ((tmp[('rs','w')] + tmp[('rs','c')])/2,
                                   (tmp[('rs','w')] - tmp[('rs','c')])/2)

(Question is exactly same but now the data is as such that I'm getting 'Value Error': after running set_index() )

Comment: What happens there is you got many row with the same, e.g. `1y  1y  in   c`, how do you know which one to choose to subtract? You should update your question with that sample and expected output. You can also create a new question...

Comment: Thanks, let me create a new question.